# Why I can't get the shadow price from Gurobipy while the model is feasible?

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I'm trying to solve peer to peer market optimization problem. Since the price of each trade between different participants can be different, I want to draw the price of each trade. And the problem should be a continuous model, because the trade amount can be at any level.

The model already works fine without problem, I can get the trade amount of each trade using like `model.variables.trade[t,k,y].x`.

But the problem is when I try to get the shadow price from the related constraints, it shows : `GurobiError: Unable to retrieve attribute 'Pi'`.

I can't find out how comes this error since the model is already feasible, and what I do is get an attribute which already exists.

The related part of my code shows as follows:

```
def _build_constraints(self):
        m = self.model
        P_nm3 = self.variables.P_nm3
        agents = self.data.agents

        timewindow = self.data.timewindow           
        windowinterval = self.data.windowinterval      
        budget = self.data.budget
        P_n = self.variables.P_n

        self.constraints.pnmmatch = {}    
        ......

        for t in self.data.interval:
            for i in range(len(P_nm3[t])):
                for j in range(len(P_nm3[t][0])):
                    self.constraints.pnmmatch[t,i,j] = m.addConstr(
                            P_nm3[t][i][j],
                            gb.GRB.EQUAL,
                            -P_nm3[t][j][i]
                            )
        .......
poolmarket = marketclear()
poolmarket.optimize()

print(poolmarket.constraints.pnmmatch[0,1,6])
print(type(poolmarket.constraints.pnmmatch))

print(poolmarket.constraints.pnmmatch[0,1,6].pi)
shadow_price = poolmarket.model.getAttr(gb.GRB.Attr.Pi)
```

The result is:

```
<gurobi.Constr R1001>
<class 'dict'>
AttributeError: Unable to retrieve attribute 'pi'
```

both `poolmarket.constraints.pnmmatch[0,1,6].pi` or `poolmarket.model.getAttr(gb.GRB.Attr.Pi)` doesn't work.
If I comment on the last two lines about pi, the models works pretty fine.

But in a simpler similar model where the constraint is:

```
        for t in self.data.interval:
            for i in range(len(P_nm3[t])):
                for j in range(len(P_nm3[t][0])):
                    self.constraints.pnmmatch[t] = m.addConstr(
                            P_nm3[t][i][j],
                            gb.GRB.EQUAL,
                            -P_nm3[t][j][i]
                            )
```

Then I'm able to draw the pi value with `poolmarket.constraints.pnmmatch[0].pi`  command.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a MIP or an LP?

Comment: I guess it's not a LP because the obj is a quadratic one like ```min (a*x^2 + b * x + c)```, but all the constraints are in LP form. The variables used in constraints are continuous and can be at any level.